# Logging so as to create a browser session using KeyCloak REST API

Tags: api, rest, session, keycloak

KeyCloak supports SAML SSO via a KeyCloak login page. After logging in here a browser session is created which allows redirection to client application webpages without further logins. This works.
However, I would like to use my own login page and scripts before redirecting users to a client application webpage.

I have been able to use the login credentials of a user (with admin rights) to successfully request an bearer access token from the Keycloak server. But this does not create a browser session.

I have not found any call in the documentation that seems like a session-creating login endpoint
(https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7294517 OR https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7294517).

Any direction or advice would be appreciated.
I work in PHP so far and have been submitting my API calls as cURL requests from PHP, sometimes testing with Postman.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You want to edit and add logic to keycloak page, or use another instead.

First option is the way to go, keycloak allows you to customize login page

Check https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-custom-login-page

If you still want to create user session from an existing token you'll need to create a new endpoint to get it.

Here you have a useful guide on how to create a custom endpoint with keycloak spi
https://medium.com/@gauravwadhone/keycloak-create-custom-rest-api-86e24bff4c1e

And here you have the code i used to get the cookies:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response get() {
    final HttpHeaders headers = session.getContext().getRequestHeaders();
    final String authorization = headers.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if(authorization == null) {
        throw new ErrorResponseException(Errors.INVALID_TOKEN, "Null authorization header",
                Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    final String[] value = authorization.split(" ");
    final String accessToken = value[1];
    final AccessToken token = Tokens.getAccessToken(accessToken, session);
    if (token == null) {
        throw new ErrorResponseException(Errors.INVALID_TOKEN, "Invalid access token", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    final RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
    final UriInfo uriInfo = session.getContext().getUri();
    final ClientConnection clientConnection = session.getContext().getConnection();
    final UserModel user = session.users().getUserById(token.getSubject(), realm);
    final UserSessionModel userSession = session.sessions().getUserSession(realm, token.getSessionState());
    AuthenticationManager.createLoginCookie(session, realm, user, userSession, uriInfo, clientConnection);
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```